# How can wildcards be used with 'graphicspath'?

Tags: graphics

When using `tikz` to draw figures they often make a mess when compiled externally (a mess of all kinds of output files, such as `.aux`).

So when using `tikz` or `pgfplots`, I like to have the structure

`figures/somecoolfigurefolder/somecoolfigure.*` ...  `figures/figureinfinity/figureinfinity.*`

I can easily add the 'figures' folder to the graphics path, but all the other subdirectories become a hassle to add individually.

So I was wondering if it is possible to use wildcards with `graphicspath` e.g. `\graphicspath{{figures/*/}}` or in another form.

for large projects I might even segment figures into chapters, and so I would also like to use `\graphicspath{{figures/*/*/}}` where the each subfolder in figures contains all figures for a single chapter, and every folder within the chapter figure folder contains a single figure, along with all needed LaTeX biproducts.

Comment: No, this is not possible: TeX doesn't really understand shell features.

Comment: @egreg is it possible to get a simmiliar effect? I don't care that it uses the `*` symbol, but I would like to read all the subfolders in the folder

Comment: If your images have unique names, you could just make `TEXINPUTS` look in all subfolders.

Comment: @samcarter so something like `export TEXINPUTS=/figures//:`?

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen For me `./figures//:` works. I did never test if it also works without the .

Comment: where should i add this line?

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen Depends on you system. If you compile from command line, it is good enough to set the environment variable in your `.bashrc` (or whatever shell you use). If you use some editor to compile, the settings depends on the operating system

Comment: @samcarter So it's impossible to do it only for a single project? it has to be system wide?

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen If you set the environment variable from within a running shell, it will only be set for the duration of this session

Comment: This seems to work, thanks a lot ;-) Would write as an answer ;-)